# How to properly pass configuration to a React Component

Tags: reactjs, npm, configuration, package

I have created a React package that I've uploaded to an NPM repo for being consumed for React Apps. What I want to achieve is to be able to set up certain parameters when consuming my component. Let's suppose that my package calls an API. This package is being used for 2 apps, App A and App B. App A needs that the component calls an url whilst App B is going to call another url. Is there any particular way to achieve this (like Axios does ie).

The main thing, I think, is that my package has a lot of components and this configuration can be used in any of them, so what I want to do is not to pass it to the root component, just having it available all the time. I have read about Context API but I am not sure if this is the correct approach or if there is even an easier way since these values are not going to be updated once the application started, these values will remain static.

Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to follow the rule "build oncedeploy everywhere"...you can put a app-config.json that contain your app config file in your public folder... in your main component you fetch that file ...

a second approach is to use .env file and use it everywhere in your app like this :`process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`...check this out https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the first option. The second one didn't work for me. I am using Roll Js to compile the package and when I build it, all those vars names are being replaced and won't work.